# power bi waterfall chart showing older date first

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am extremely new to powerbi. Just about 3 days in. With that said I am having an issue with the waterfall chart. It is showing newer year first and with that it gives an incorrect percentage increase/decrease in sales because of it. See example below:[image]

[image]

I want the first year to be 2017's netsales first then 2018's net sale. I Believe this should fix my problem.

Comment: Can you show what fields you put in Category/Breakdown/Y Axis?

Comment: I updated the post with the Category/Breakdown/Y Axis

Comment: You need to create an index to sort your dates by

Comment: thank you @stelio. i am very new to this, how do i do this?

Comment: @CastellJames something like this should help: https://databear.com/power-bi-tips-sort-by-month-name/

Comment: that link was very useful, thanks. However, it does not appear that it can help with my situation as I am not trying to order month/days of the week names in the correct order. I do believe that the link is useful for other scenarios but given that the year is a number it should I be able to order it ascending order.